# What is the use case for CQL batch statements?

Tags: cassandra, cql

Lets say I want to create a table that allows interchangeable and optional use of queries. Lets use the example from the [Cassandra Community Webinar | Become a Super Modeler Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=qphhxujn5Es#t=2019) on youtube.

Here is what my table looks like after inserting only one car:

```
 make | model   | color | vehical_id | lot_id
------+---------+-------+------------+--------
 FORD |         |       |       1234 | 654321
 FORD |         |  BLUE |       1234 | 654321
      | MUSTANG |  BLUE |       1234 | 654321
      |         |  BLUE |       1234 | 654321
 FORD | MUSTANG |  BLUE |       1234 | 654321
 FORD | MUSTANG |       |       1234 | 654321
      | MUSTANG |       |       1234 | 654321
```

with the primary key being: `PRIMARY KEY ((make, model, color),vehical_id)`

Now I can select by `make`, `make AND model` and all other combinations of `make`, `model`, and `color` as these make up my primary key.

And the inserts it took to insert that one car:

```
INSERT INTO car_location_index (make, model, color, vehical_id, lot_id) VALUES ('FORD', MUSTANG', 'BLUE', 1234, 654321);
INSERT INTO car_location_index (make, model, color, vehical_id, lot_id) VALUES ('FORD','MUSTANG', '', 1234, 654321);
INSERT INTO car_location_index (make, model, color, vehical_id, lot_id) VALUES ('FORD', '', 'BLUE', 1234, 654321);    
INSERT INTO car_location_index (make, model, color, vehical_id, lot_id) VALUES ('', 'MUSTANG', 'BLUE', 1234, 654321);
INSERT INTO car_location_index (make, model, color, vehical_id, lot_id) VALUES ('FORD', '', '', 1234, 654321);
INSERT INTO car_location_index (make, model, color, vehical_id, lot_id) VALUES ('', 'MUSTANG', '', 1234, 654321);
INSERT INTO car_location_index (make, model, color, vehical_id, lot_id) VALUES ('', '', 'BLUE', 1234, 654321);
```

If something went wrong while inserting here, I would be able to find this car with some search combinations, but not others. So in this instance the data would be corrupted if some of the inserts failed. **For this reasoning is it justified to use a batch statement to surround all of my inserts?** (`BEGIN BATCH ... APPLY BATCH;`)

**If it is not, why and what is the proper use case of a batch statement?**

**Bonus would be descriptions on the specifics of how batch statements are implemented.**

Thanks for any guidance,

Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the case.
Row writing is atomic by default but multiple rows writing is not atomic unless you don't use a logged batch. Take care when using Logged Batches: consider about a 30% loss of performance in write-time due to atomicity guarantees.

Further informations can be found here: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/atomic-batches-in-cassandra-1-2

Cheers,
Carlo